# How do I process a pandas dataframe more efficiently than by looping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am processing a pandas dataframe in **PYTHON**. How can I create a calculation to resolve this without using loop as it takes up too much time due to large dataset. This is the formula that is required to calculate 'stock' column.

```
stock = supply - demand + previous day stock (Assume 0 stock on day 1)
```

However, if previous day stock is **negative**, we will calculate with 0 stock in the formula

```
stock = supply - demand + 0
```

| day | demand | supply | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 21 | 10 |
| 2 | 11 | 0 | -1 |
| 3 | 11 | 0 | -11 |
| 4 | 11 | 23 | 12 |
| 5 | 11 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 11 | 0 | -10 |
| 7 | 11 | 0 | -11 |

Providing a sample reference below:

```
pd.DataFrame({'day': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'demand':
[11,11,11,11,11,11,11],'supply':[21,0,0,23,0,0,0]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you *can* do this without looping. Each stock row is dependent on every row that came before it, and so you can't vectorise this calculation (which would require independent operations).

I would just use a loop like this

```
stock = np.zeros(len(df)).astype(int)
sd_diff = df["supply"] - df["demand"]
stock[0] = sd_diff[0]
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    stock[i] = sd_diff[i] + max(0, stock[i - 1])
df["stock"] = stock
```